# Convert SQL to JPA with ORDER BY clause

Tags: kotlin, jpa

I have got the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT sign,todayVal 
FROM EXCHANGE E
ORDER BY FIELD(E.sign,
    "USD" ,"GBP" ,"CAD" ,"CHF" ,"HKD"
        ,"SEK" ,"AUD" ,"DKK" ,"NOK" ,"SAR")
```

How can I convert it into JPA?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `ORDER BY`, if there is no column right for sorting you will need to create one

If you want that query called by JPA you use `@Query` annotation on method in your repository like so

```
@Query("your query")
Collection<Table> method();
```